# Anti-link doesn't delete messages discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I wrote this code for detecting links in messages, but it doesn't delete the message or send the embed logs! And also there is no error shown in terminal. I've tried `console.log()` the message in the `if` statement and it seems detected!

[This is my code](https://srcb.in/MjJioFf4tW)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `const split = content.split("");
if(split.length >= 2000) return embed.setDescription(`${split.toString} ...`);
if(split.length < 2000) return embed.setDescription(`${content} `);`
Why you need split then check length? it's unnecessary.

Comment: And [here](https://srcb.in/eCoufOuxIJ) is an edited version of your large code:

Comment: And why do you `return`? Everything below that will be ignored. And why do you use `split`? Why would you need an array of characters? And lots of more questions...

Comment: I don't do early return just because there may be some code after.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished easier using regex checker

```js
const {
    guild,
    channel,
    content
} = message;
const linklog = guild.channels.cache.get("995975097909248031");


const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${message.member} try to send a link in ${channel} with message: \n  `);


if(/http:|https:|discord.gg|www./gi.test(message.content)){
    let split = content.split("");
    if (split.length >= 2000){
        embed.setDescription(`${split.toString} ...`);
    } else {
        embed.setDescription(`${content}`);
    }
   
    await linklog.send({
        content: `<@${message.author.id}> tried to send links in <#${message.channel.id}>`,
        embeds: [embed]
    });
    await message.delete();
    await channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}> No links here`);
}
```